# Autocomplete is not working for me using materialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to use the new Form autocomplete and i tried it but there is no dropdown list opening up and suggesting the words for searching.
The class="autocomplete" should be added for jquery $(input.autocomplete).....and my jquery code is....

```
$("#productName").keyup(function (e) {
var min_length = 0;
var keyword = $('#productName').val();
$(function () {
if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
$.ajax({
url: "/getSearchedProductName",
type: 'POST',
datatype: 'JSON',
data: {
method: 'getSearchedProductName',
keyword: keyword
},
success: function (response) {
response = JSON.parse(response);
var projects = new Array();
var array = new Array();
var arr = new Array();
$.each(response.data, function (key, value) {
var projects = {
value1: value.product_name,
value2: value.image_url
};
array.push(projects);
});
$(function () {
$("#productName").autocomplete({
data: {
"Google": 'http://placehold.it/250x250',
"G1": 'http://placehold.it/250x250',
"G2": 'http://placehold.it/250x250',
"Go3": 'http://placehold.it/250x250',
"G4": 'http://placehold.it/250x250'
};

.autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
return $("<li>").append("<div class='autocomplete-content dropdown-  content' data-id=" + item.value + ">" + item.label + "</div>")
                                        .appendTo(ul);
};

if (e.which === 13) {
$.each(response.data, function (i, v) {
var prodID = v['product_id'];
if (prodID != null) {
window.location = webUrl + "/categorySearchItems?productId=" + prodID;
}
});
}
});
}
});
}
});
});
```

For autocomplete searching I used the cdn script:

If it works for someone else then please show me how to make it work for me.
if someone have any link for autocomplete then share me.

Comment: It would be nice to have a link of your code hosted on jsFiddle but here is mine http://jsfiddle.net/LCv8L/1110/

Comment: its working,thanks..

Answer (score 0):

There is a little problem in your code. As you must be knowing that materialize's autocomplete facility works with input-field. 
Hence, you must provide a class to one of the `text-type-input` element which is within div of class `input-field`

```
$("#productName").autocomplete({
  data: {
    "Google": 'http://placehold.it/250x250',
    "G1": 'http://placehold.it/250x250',
    "G2": 'http://placehold.it/250x250',
    "Go3": 'http://placehold.it/250x250',
    "G4": 'http://placehold.it/250x250'
  };
```

What I guess, the code should look like -

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
  data: {
    "Google": 'http://placehold.it/250x250',
    "G1": 'http://placehold.it/250x250',
    "G2": 'http://placehold.it/250x250',
    "Go3": 'http://placehold.it/250x250',
    "G4": 'http://placehold.it/250x250'
  }
});
```

The above code defines `input` element's class `autocomplete`.
Guess this helps.